# Why cosine basis for determining bandwidth?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

Instead of Fourier transform with cosines for example, one could use a square waves basis, then a pure cosine wave would have a broad bandwidth.

The question is why the cosines seems more fundamental than let say a triangle or squares, since one could express cosines in those basis functions ?

Comment: This is actually more of a Math SE question. But I think your example is a naive interpretation. There are more requirements than that. One of them is orthogonality I believe. There *are* other approaches to separating signals into orthogonal constituents other than Fourier such as "wavelets".

Comment: I think they are orthogonal, but I believe sine waves come from vibration of an instrument chord or an alternator, but if we take electronic signals from computers those are square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin/cosine are the eigenvectors of the wave equation in unbounded domains, thus they form the natural basis for expressing solutions to and properties of wave phenomena.

Comment: Ah yes. The inevitable answer which I like to call the dreaded "MATH HAMMER".

Comment: I don't know anymore howto diagonalize that operator. I tried separation of variables $$u(x)v(t)$$ and got stuck on the ode $$u'(x)=\sqrt{cu(x)^2+C}$$, I shouls be on the wrong way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For the eigenvalue zero the eigenvectors are any functions $$f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$$ for example

Comment: Is it correct to write : $$f(x-vt)$$ leading to $$(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})f''(u)=\lambda f(u)$$ for the eigenproblem, with $$f(u)=\sin(ku)$$ thus it is an eigenfunction for the eigenvalue $$\lambda=(1-v^2/c^2)k^2$$ ?