# Is there anything special about sinusoidal EM waves? How does the strength of a purely sinusoidal EM wave vary with distance from the source?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform, lienard-wiechert

In this [atoms and sporks video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZnXhRgztEg), the narrator mentions that not all Electromagnetic (EM) waves have to be sinusoidal. In fact, he gives a nice animation of such a case at 16:42.

He talks about a different way to think about EM called "retarded potential" and mentions the LW (Lienard-Wiechert) equation (shown at 13:14):

$$\vec E(\vec r, t) = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{|\vec r(t_{past})|}{(\vec r(t_{past}) \cdot \vec v(t_{past}))^3}\Big[(c^2-\vec v(t_{past})^2)\big(c \hat r(t_{past}) - \vec v(t_{past})\big) \ + \ \vec r(t_{past}) \ \times \ \big(c\hat r(t_{past}) - \vec v(t_{past})\big) \times \vec a(t_{past})\Big]$$

He explains there are two parts to the equation, one related to the position-velocity vector and another related to the position-velocity-acceleration vector. The former may be called the static part and the latter he calls the radiating part. At any rate, a couple of the important take-aways of the video were:

- EM waves don't have to be sinusoidal
- the static part of the EM field (i.e. the part due solely to position and velocity of a charge) dies down at $1/r^2$ (like Coulomb's law says).
- the radiating part of the EM field (i.e. the part due to position, velocity, and acceleration of a charge) dies down at a much slower rate of $1/r$, but it still dies down.

My question is: I've heard sinusoidal EM waves described as self-sustaining, so that suggests (to me) that their strength is maintained. Is this true?

This video was the first time I was exposed to non-sinusoidal EM waves. It's always been implied that EM waves are sinusoidal and that doesn't seem to be. I'm trying to reconcile this new knowledge by figuring out if there *is* something special about sinusoidal EM waves - one way they might still be special is their field strength is maintained...

Comment: I view this question as essentially the same as this one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/671522/10635  -- why do we *focus* on EM waves with a particular frequency when doing math.  It's because it's easier to solve the problems in this domain, and we can (in principle) recover the time-domain solution by taking the inverse Fourier transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've heard sinusoidal EM waves described as self-sustaining, so that suggests (to me) that their strength is maintained. Is this true?

The determining factor for whether a wave dies down is not whether it's sinusoidal;  it's whether or not you can treat it as as plane wave rather than a spherical one.  If you take the expression you've written down and apply it to a charge moving in simple harmonic motion ($\vec{r}(t) = \cos (\omega t) \hat{z}$ or something like that) then you'll get a spherical wave whose radiation field (in the "far region" you mentioned) is proportional to $\sin(k r- \omega t)/r$ with some phase shift.  So it is entirely possible to have sinusoidal waves that "die off" as you get farther away.

On the other hand, we can also derive the wave equation for $\vec{E}$ from Maxwell's equations in vacuum, which is
$$
\nabla^2 \vec{E} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \vec{E}}{\partial t^2}
$$
and under the assumption that $\vec{E}$ does not depend on $x$ or $y$, this reduces to the 1-D wave equation for all three Cartesian components of $\vec{E}$:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial z^2} = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial t^2}
$$
Any function of the form $E_x(z,t) = f(z - ct) + g(z+ct)$ will satisfy this equation (try it and check!).  These will correspond to plane wave solutions, but they need not be sinusoidal unless the functions $f$ or $g$ are sinusoidal;  you can drop any old function into the above (a pulse function, say) and the wave will still maintain a constant amplitude as it travels in $z$.

You can also show, by the way, that for the scalar wave equation
$$
\nabla^2 \phi = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}
$$
the general solution that only depends on $r$ and $t$ is
$$
\phi(r,t) = \frac{1}{r} \left(f(r - ct) + g(r+ct)\right).
$$
If $f$ is a "pulse" function (and $g = 0$), this corresponds to a pulse traveling outwards from the origin whose amplitude decreases with $r$.  This again confirms the idea that the factor that makes waves die out with distance is not whether they are sinusoidal, but rather whether they are spherical.

In real life, of course, plane waves don't exist.  But they are easier to understand for students learning the subject;  they are a particularly useful mathematical construct (as noted in the comments on the OP); and we can approximate a spherical wave as a plane wave in small regions of space far away from the wave source.  So they're still a useful idea even if they don't arise, strictly speaking, in the real world.

Comment: If you consider a small solid angle leaving a (small ) source of a wave, unless focused the energy of the wave must spread out over the area which defines the solid angle.  That area increases with the square of the distance, so the energy per unit area must decrease with the square of the distance.

Comment: @R.W.Bird:  Agreed.  There's probably another good answer that could be given using energy arguments (along the lines of what you've written.)